# JQuery UI Resizable + box-sizing: border-box = height bug?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resizable

I'm trying to resize a DIV with box-sizing: border-box;
Even though I only allow resizing the width, the DIV shrinks everytime the resize event stops (height changes).

My CSS

```
.test{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').resizable({handles: 'e', stop: function(event, ui){
        $('.wdt').text(ui.size.height);
    }});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="test">
    Test
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Height =</span>
<span class='wdt'></span>
```

Resize it and you will see.

Can anybody help me?
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuQtw/4/

I tried jquery 1.8.x.. 1.9.x... nothing changes.
I cant use box-sizing: content-box.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why it's happening, but it seems your `border` property is the issue.

If you want it to function the same, you can use `outline` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/WuQtw/10/

```
.test{
    width:200px;
    height: 100px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have padding on the element. The issue is related to the way Jquery UI Resizable calculates the element width. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8932

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered the same problem and build this snippet - may it helps someone.

```
// initiate correction
var iHeightCorrection = 0;

var oElement = $('#elementToResize');

// init resize
oElement.resizable({
        handles: 's',
        minHeight: 30,
        // on start of resize
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // calculate correction
            iHeightCorrection = $(oElement).outerHeight() - $(oElement).height();
        },
        // on resize
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            // manual correction
            ui.size.height += iHeightCorrection;
        },
        // on stop of resize
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // reset correction
            iHeightCorrection = 0;
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud1hczoz/1/)

Comment: Works perfectly... I did not define the correction on the start event but rather calculated it on resize for each call:

const correction = $(ui.element).outerHeight() - $(ui.element).height();

Answer (score 0):

isthiswhat you are looking for baby?

just wait one year to update  jquery to 2.0.2

and then it works

http://jsfiddle.net/WuQtw/37/

```js
//it worked on jsfiddle using  jQuery UI 1.10.3
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('.test').resizable({ 
      
      stop: function(event, ui){
        
        $('.wdt').text(ui.size.height);
        
    }});
});
```

```css
.test{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
      Test
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>Height =</span>
<span class='wdt'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issued by wrapping the element.  Use a div with a border of 0 to wrap your original element.

```
.wrapperDiv {
    position:absolute; 
    height:100px; 
    width:100px; 
    border: 0px;
}

.innerDiv{
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 3px solid gold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
...
var tSelectionDiv = $('<div class="wrapperDiv"><div class="innerDiv"></div></div>');
...
tSelectionDiv.resizable({
    handles: 'e, w', 
    containment:someContainerElement
});
```